# How to linkify @usernames and #hashtags with jquery.linkify Plugin

Tags: jquery, regex, linkify, hashtag

I'm using this jquery plugin: https://github.com/maranomynet/linkify/blob/master/1.0/jquery.linkify-1.0.js

With this REGEX plugins I'm trying to linkify @usernames and #hashtags...

```
  linkify.plugins = {
  tUser: {
      re: /(^|\s)@(\w+)/gi,
      tmpl: '$1@<a href="http://domain.com/$2">$2</a>'
  },
  tHashtag: {
      re: /(^|["'(]|&lt;|\s)(#.+?)((?:[:?]|\.+)?(?:\s|$)|&gt;|[)"',])/gi,
      tmpl: function (match, pre, hashTag, post) {
            return pre+'<a href="http://domain.com/search.php?q='+ encodeURIComponent(hashTag) +'">'+hashTag+'</a>'+post;
      }
  }
};
```

... but I'm having some troubles with odd combinations:

(In **BOLD** what should be linkified but is not)

[#hash](http://hash) **#hash**) ([#hash](http://hash)) /**#hash**

@[user](http://user) @[user](http://user)) (@**user**) /@**user**

Any idea on how could I fix the REGEX to match this variations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with linkify, but I'll give this a shot.

The problem with the first regex (**@user**) is that it isn't matching because it requires leading whitespace or newline -- that's the `(^|\s)` part. As for the **#hash** regex, well... that seems unnecessarily complex. Try the following:

```
linkify.plugins = {
  tUser: {
    re: /(^|\s|[^\w\d])@(\w+)/gi,
    tmpl: '$1@<a href="http://domain.com/$2">$2</a>'
  },
  tHashtag: {
    re: /(^|\s|[^\w\d])#(\w+)/gi,
    tmpl: function (match, pre, hashTag) {
            return pre+'<a href="http://domain.com/search.php?q='+
                   encodeURIComponent(hashTag) +'">#'+hashTag+'</a>';
    }
  }
};
```

This will match either the **@user** or **#hash** so long as they are preceded by a newline, whitespace or a non-word, non-digit character (not a-z, A-Z or 0-9). So your parenthesis won't interfere, but most email addresses won't be picked up either.

Note that the hash symbol won't be included on your search on the linkified hash-tags either.

Comment: Something to note is that the hashtags and usernames will only match if they are all letters. So `#my-tag` will just match the `#my` part. If your hash can include dashes and underscores, for example, then you can change the `(\w+)` part of the regex to `([\w\-_]+)`

Comment: Thanks Dave! That works just great. The hashtag was working with accented characters like áéíóú, is possible to add that in the new Regex? Thanks again!

Comment: Sure. Just use `/(^|\s|[^\w\d])#([\wáéíóú]+)/gi`. Or, alternatively, decide on which characters you *don't* want to match on the hash tags, i.e. where it should terminate its match. If it is whitespace, then replace the `(\w+)` with `(.+)\s` and then add a space after your `</a>`. Hope that helps.